# decrypting FileVault2 WDE seems stuck, how to unstick?

Tags: macos, filevault, encryption

This is happening on an MBP Mid2010 running Mac OS X 10.9.3

I have been using FileVault2 full-disk encryption for several years now; however, I needed to decrypt to repartition the disk for BootCamp. I initiated decryption through Security and Privacy section of System Preferences. It's been stuck in "Decrypting... estimating time remaining" ever since (for about three days now), like this:

[image: img]

It also persists through reboots (twice now). The good part is it boots, the bad part is it is still stuck. I have googled around to gain some commandline-fu, but the results are just confusing me. Here are some results:

```
$ diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4C4E3BF0-E73A-4BF7-8A8C-2C43981FBB23
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         499248103424 B (499.2 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 5239F8A2-7636-4596-8BAC-8715A2D6946A
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     499248103424 B (499.2 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 51D0AB7B-0C06-4E0E-808A-80453841F0D5
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       Converting
        Conversion Direction:    backward
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume D5A2568B-31DB-4EC9-BE30-7445EEA18127
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          498929332224 B (498.9 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

also, if I try this:

```
$ sudo fdesetup disable
Password:
Error: FileVault is Off.
```

it says it IS off.

Could someone enlighten me to what exactly is going on, and how do I unstick this process to some kind of understandable status, from which I could safely proceed? (yes I have backups, but I would prefer not to go full reinstall if at all possible)

Comment: June 23rd… Has it finished by now?

Comment: Nope. There is no progress. Part of the system thinks it is not encrypted, and another part thinks it is encrypted.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response… I asked because I was stuck at reboot (rotating throbber) after turning FileVault off, but in a few hours I lost my patience, rebooted hard and it decrypted just fine after the normal boot…